# Installing only changed modules in maven project and updating only changed modules' version number

Tags: maven, versioning, multi-module

first of all sorry for the long title. I am working on a multi-module maven project. Right now, project have only 1 version, that is parent version. Also, making an "mvn install" takes long time since all modules are installed one by one. My purpose is to install only the modules that are changed, and the ones that are dependent on it. And then I want to change the versions of modules-which are properties in parent pom- that are changed.

So far, I get changed files via following command(my purpose is to take a commit id via command line instead of getting diff relative to HEAD, but for development purposes, HEAD is fine):

```
git diff HEAD | grep '^diff --git [A-Za-z0-9 ]*' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -c 3-
```

which gets relative paths(according to parent directory of project) of changed files. With this information I detect changed modules, change their versions in parent pom.xml file(they are set as property in parent pom)

As a side note, I am doing all this via a python bash script.

I want to install changed nodules via command:

```
mvn -pl module1,module2.. -amd install
```

What I cannot resolve right now is that for some modules, -pl command won't work because I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project bla-bla: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz.bla:bla-bla:jar:2.10.0:
```

When I executed above command with debug logging enabled, I realized that problem is probably maven not evaluating parent pom and thus not understanding:

```
com.xyz.bla:bla-some_other_bla:${bla-someother-bla-version}
```

meaning that it cannot resolve version property on child pom, thus cannot find jar on local repository and fail to accomplish an install.

I want to know if this way is a good way to achieve what I wanna achieve and how to resolve this dependency problem. If you know both, then please state both since I have a limited time to complete the work, I may presume with the current solution:)

Notes:

- I have tried to use https://github.com/nwiechmann/scm-changes-maven-extension but failed to get it working.
- mvn:release plugin :updateversions does not support multiple version updates, so this probably is not an option.

All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a multi module build is having only a single version number for all modules, cause all modules will be released at the same time.

You might improve that and only build those modules which have changed which can be achieved via [this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/incremental-module-builder). And also [this might help](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2016/08/08/maven-how-to-create-a-release/) in particular for the property which can be used as a version number.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I asked project leader about versioning stuff and he says that modules are actually released separately and this is why they want them to have different version numbers.

Comment: If they are released separately it means a multi module build does not make sense...